# Paperclip: NoMethodError (undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, nomethoderror

I've looked all over the internet trying to find why this error is happening to me.
I'm trying to upload a file using paperclip gem in Rails 3.2.7 and is giving me this error:

```
NoMethodError in ItemsController#create

undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass

Rails.root: C:/Users/AC_37-PC_BH/RubymineProjects/railstutorial-sample_app_2nd_ed-815d98a

app/controllers/items_controller.rb:20:in `new'
app/controllers/items_controller.rb:20:in `create'

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"oYc/V2xKpJVKXPukjrjzQJAboOxI27YXPI42sfDHYaA=",
 "item"=>{"item_name"=>"",
 "item_pic"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x3c36678 @original_filename="197623_10150112121221032_1900156_n.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"item[item_pic]\"; filename=\"197623_10150112121221032_1900156_n.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
 @tempfile=#<File:C:/Users/AC_37-~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20120801-6096-q8c9v0>>},
 "commit"=>"Create my account"}
```

I'm including a github to the project so you guys can test it. And try to see what's wrong.
You have to manually access the localhost:3000/items/new to see the page

https://github.com/vinchbr/demo_app

All help would be much appreciated =)

Comment: The github project you linked doesn't seem to be the same as the code you're mentioning here - the exception points to an issue inside items_controller.rb at line 20 (inside the `create` method), but line 20 inside the github project is the `show` method.

Comment: I think I removed a lot of useless code that is generated by scaffold that might be why it is on the wrong place =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put into **Gemfile**:

The following code:

```
gem 'paperclip', '3.0.4'
```